# Migrating to cs.SE as a "flag" option

Tags: discussion, migration, flagging

Currently non-moderators can flag off-topic posts and suggest that it either belongs in meta or on stackoverflow. It seems that cs.SE is a target that makes at least as much sense as stackoverflow for a suggested location where the post belongs. Should there be an option for flaggers to suggest the post belongs on cs.SE?

Comment: See http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/migration-path-from-cstheory-to-cs-se, which seems to be the de facto "official" version of this question with answers from cs.SE folks and from SE moderators.

Answer (score 8):

I think the general SE attitude is that until graduation, migration to a beta site should not be done (since the site might just go away), so we should wait till [cs.se] exits beta and launches.

ps: since the betas are taking much longer these days, they might have reconsidered this attitude, but even in this case it is too early to add the migration option to the list.

Comment: But you *are* already migrating, so what harm can it do?

Comment: @Raphael, I guess that SE would reply that we should have waited a little bit more before starting migrating questions to [cs.se].

Comment: If the question will be closed, there's no benefit to the person asking just because the SE site it's on doesn't close. Whereas the beta could substantially benefit from the question being put where it belongs. It seems perverse to keep the question from going where it belongs ad might actually be answered, if the place where it belongs would benefit from getting the question transferred to them.