# In which way this question is a research level?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging

I flagged this [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19354/complexity-of-blind-sort) as *needs moderator attention* and in my reason I wrote, is not a research level, but moderator rejected the flag. I want to know in which way someone can consider it as a research level?

If the reason of rejection is because I didn't flag it as *other* to close it, my reason is because I'm really confused about the use of migration (that I don't like it myself) and flagging for close (e.g [this](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2734/the-number-of-custom-close-reasons) and [this](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1509/migrating-to-cs-se-as-a-flag-option) and many similar topics are contradicting each other and is not clear for me to pick which one as a rule, and I don't want to discuss a long time to make it clear, I hope moderators get managed to do it themselves), e.g in this specific question seems OP doesn't know the basic search term, then we should consider it as research level question?

Comment: I think the question is borderline, and could be asked here or CS.SE. Since this is a first time asker, I think we should give him the benefit of the doubt. If it was a person that repeatedly asks questions that are borderline then I would vote to close. If you are unhappy with the question then I recommend down-voting it; votes carry very useful information and I don't think enough people use them!

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev, This sounds to be a reasonable answer, if you write it as an answer is much more better.

Answer (score 4):

I think the question is perfectly reasonable, under the category of "people asking questions where if they knew the right terms, they'd be able to get the answer". As a moderator (not the one who deleted your flag), I'd do the same thing because you can very easily vote to close the question if you don't like it. Moderator flagging should be used for things that the community cannot deal with on its own, or that need urgent attention (like offensive comments for example)

Comment: I cannot vote to close, because I don't have that privilage, I just can flag it (otherwise I was going to close it, and I said flagging reason is not clear to me, so I used moderator attention part to put my reason). Also by your reasoning I have many research level questions (because I never tried to find the correct search term for them), then I have to ask them and is reasonable?

Comment: I think it depends on the question. As for the flagging, one option (since you can't vote to close) if you think the question is inappropriate is to downvote it and/or post a comment.

Comment: @Saeed, I agree with Suresh. I rejected the flag for the reason he explains in this answer. Please use flags only when there is something that _requires_ a moderator intervention. Also see [assuming good faith for naïve questions](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/).

Comment: Ok, Then, really I cannot understand why flags are available? Why there is an off topic option? why there is a close reason in flag? P.S: I usually don't like to downvote questions which are well stated. and downvote to me does not mean as a close option. P.S2: All of above are moderators ideas, I respect them, but these are not convincing for me, and I didn't said above questions (in my comment) to get an answer for them. It's just to express my opinion.

Comment: @Saeed, the answer to your whys is rather simple: because we have not designed the software! Each SE site has it's own site specific norms and policies and as you can see from the linked discussion this is not just the opinion of the moderators, there is a strong support from cstheory community for community-centered moderation of the site as much as possible. If you cannot vote to close and don't want to down-vote then the option that remains for you is to comment and express your opinion and move on and let those who have enough reputation to cast close votes decide the question's faith.

Comment: @Kaveh, Ok, then is good to ask SE support to delete the unnecessary flag options and show them that community supports you (if you didn't do this), I cannot guess that some flag exists but they are for fun and community don't like them. But, here I asked a specific question about specific question to make something clear, the flagging *options* is a side question and is not important here.

Comment: @Saeed, the flag is not useless, but it should be used only when a moderator action is suitable. For the particular question as you can see there are no close votes on the question so others don't agree with you about the off-topicness of the question therefore it is going to remain open.

Comment: @Kaveh, If you want to talk about a flag, I said there are some flag *options* which are useless by your or Suresh's definitions (not flags, now go back to my previous comment). If you want to talk about this particular question, I said that (in my question), I cannot understand why this question is research level, it has nothing to do with others opinion, I just was wonder, so I asked a question. (I don't want to spend time to discuss about this, I'm disagree with you/Suresh and possibly all others, and I don't want to convince someone, I just said my opinion, you can take it or leave it).

Comment: @Saeed: having seen moderators make some really bad decisions, I am definitely in favor of having moderators use their powers sparingly. If the community doesn't feel that the question needs to be closed, why should it be closed?

Comment: @PeterShor, Actually my concern was about the research level part of question. By current (rigid) definition of a research level in FAQ, this question is not in this category, because in many text books of algorithms or wiki, OP can find better structure than his trivial structure. Also looking at a text book (not reading thorough, just chapter titles and looking into chapters to see if is somehow relevant),takes at most 1,2 or 7 days for someone who just knows some basics of CS. So I cannot classify it as a research level. -->

Comment: @PeterShor, Also upvotes, are not really causing to be a research level. e.g Here upvotes are in two categories (in my humble opinion): some people like it, some people want to say to OP that they are not agree with my comment and this type of question is welcome in their opinion. In neither case the question is great and this upvotes doesn't improve the quality of site. If I like some topic or new topics doesn't mean I should upvote simple questions, without any effort (research level effort I mean). -->

Comment: On the other hand if you look at an answer, answer is very simple answer, just a link farm, with a claim without any evidence or proof, and this answer also got many upvotes, these sort of upvotes even if they are thousands, doesn't prove anything. (Everyone is free to upvote or downvote by his reason, but this does not imply that the question is research level).

Comment: @Saeed: you are free to vote the question down, vote to close it, or put up a comment encouraging other users to vote to close it. I just feel very strongly that whether a question is acceptable for the website should be decided by the ***users*** and not the ***moderators***. Moderators should only be closing questions which obviously do not belong, or are blatant spam, or are offensive. cstheory.SE should belong to the users, and not the moderators.

Comment: @PeterShor, Yes agreed. May be I should rephrase my question. But I think we both understand what the other one wants to say.